# Variable within for loop to be new iterator for outer loop Python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Suppose I have the following example code:

```
element = xmlDoc.find("...") # this returns an element that is found within an XML document
for child in element.getchildren():
    # iterate over each child
    # do some stuff
    if some_condition: # assume that at some point in the loop, this condition is executed
        element = xmlDoc.find("..." # find a new element in the doc and this element should be the new element to iterate over from the next loop
```

This is obviously very theoretical at this point. What I'm trying to do is start off a loop by looking into each children nodes of a certain "element" node. However, if some_condition is executed (which it will be at some point in my code), then I would like the very next for loop iteration to use the new "element" variable within that if statement. Therefore, I would expect the next loop iteration to loop over each child node of the "new" element, rather than the one that was started off from the first iteration

Is there any way that I can do this?

Comment: Please explain your use case / actual goal instead of this very specific requirement without giving a motivation; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Also, include a minimal, reproducible code example and your expected output, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
sequence = iter(xmlDoc.find("...").getchildren())
while True:
    try:
        element = next(sequence)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    # handle element ...
    if some_condition:
        sequence = iter(xmlDoc.find("...").getchildren())
```

Comment: Thank you! I figured a while loop was required. Do you know how I may be able to change the for loop of `for child in element.getchildren():` into a `while`?